# How to read files content as parameter batch file

Tags: batch-file, io

I want to read values stored in series of .txt files (formatted same way), as parameters followed to another command.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=    " %%A IN ( TestName.txt ) DO CALL :Process %%A %%B %%C
:Process
ECHO [1] = "%1"
ECHO [2] = "%2"
ECHO [3] = "%3"
GOTO :eof
```

Everything is ok, when IN (...) has direct reference to single text file (except one empty run at the end).
Results:

```
[1] = "TestValue11"
[2] = "TestValue21"
[3] = "TestValue31"
[1] = "TestValut12"
[2] = "TestValue22"
[3] = "TestValue32"
[1] = ""
[2] = ""
[3] = ""
```

TestName.txt looks like:

```
TestValue11 TestValue21 TestValue31
TestValut12 TestValue22 TestValue32
```

But when I would like to set a path to TestName.txt placed in another directory than %~dp0, let's say "input", only filname is readed as first parameter. The loop is not entering into files anymore.

I've tried path placed `IN ( )` as following:

```
IN ("%~dp0input\*.txt")
```

or

```
IN ('DIR /A-D /B "%~dp0input\*.txt"')
```

---

Could you help me make this loop more usefull, that values from many files can be readed?

Comment: The empty values are because after your loop finishes, your script still goes through the `Process` command. You can add a `goto :eof` just before the `Process` label.

Comment: Also you don't need to reference `%~dp0` before the `input\` path... Just put the directory path normally as you would do without the `%dp0`. Run your script with `@echo on` so you see what's really happening.

Comment: `%~dp0` is the parent directory of the batch file itself; to use any path, put it like `IN ("\path\to\your\file.txt")`, given you have specified the `usebackq` option; note that `for /F` does not support wildcards like `*`and `?`, so if you specify `*.txt`, `for /F` tries to find a file named `*.txt` which cannot be found of course...

Comment: Daniel, thanks for tip,  I missed that goto label writing test case only for that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

1. There is no `GOTO :eof` after the `FOR /F` loop, so you fall into the `:Process` routine unintentionally after completion of the loop.
2. You should put quotes around the arguments of `CALL :Process`, because characters like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;` and `=` are treated as delimiters otherwise. You can remove these quotes later in the `:Process` sub-routine using the `~` modifier like `%~1`, etc.
3. Since file paths and names may contain white-spaces, you should enclose them in quotation marks `""`. `FOR /F` treats quoted strings as literal strings rather than as file names, unless you provide the option string `usebackq`.
4. `FOR /F` does not support wildcards like `*` and `?`, so when you specify `*.txt`, `FOR /F` tries to find a file named `*.txt`, which cannot be found of course. To overcome this, you can wrap around a standard `FOR` loop which does support wildcards.

Here is the fixed script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("\full\path\to\your\files\*.txt") DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=    " %%A IN ("%%~fF") DO CALL :Process "%%A" "%%B" "%%C"
)
GOTO :eof

:Process
ECHO [1] = "%~1"
ECHO [2] = "%~2"
ECHO [3] = "%~3"
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: That was really helpful !  
Only one `%` sign is missing (in first FOR loop)  
I've made similar assumption reading [this subject](http://serverfault.com/questions/508583/parse-all-text-files-in-a-folder-using-for-f-command), but your post was quicker and more into point ! Appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for your FOR /F to parse out the individual parameters, given that you are simply going to put them all back together again.

Even if you wanted to parse them out, it would be difficult to do because the rules for how FOR /F parses tokens are entirely different than how the command line parser works.

The following should be all you need:

```
@echo off
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A IN ( TestName.txt ) do call :Process %%A
exit /b

:Process
echo [1] = "%1"
echo [2] = "%2"
echo [3] = "%3"
exit /b
```

The odd DELIMS and EOL syntax effectively disables both options, so each entire line is preserved.

As others have pointed out, an EXIT /B (or GOTO :EOF) is needed after your FOR loop.